# insert $_SESSION['MM_Username'] in to log message

Tags: php, mysql, session, insert

First post here - I've been learning php and mysql for a month or so now.

I'm trying to post the session 'MM_Username' into log notes.
so it reads 'archived by username'

I thought that if I set the lognote value to 'archived by " . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . "'
I would get the result i was after. Apparently not.

What am I doing wrong?
My code is below.

Thanks

```
    if ((isset($_GET['divisionid'])) && ($_GET['divisionid'] != "")) {


  $logarchiveSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO log (logaction, logdivisionid, lognotes) VALUES ('Division Archived', %s, 'archived by " . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . "')",
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['divisionid'], "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
  $Result2 = mysql_query($logarchiveSQL, $connect) or die(mysql_error());


  $updateGoTo = "../divisions.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));}
```

Comment: I'm not getting an error, the query works - I just cannot get the query to post the SESSION['MM_Username'] into the lognotes value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you remembered to put it session_start(); before trying to access your sessions?

Answer (score 0):

What result are you getting? Is the query actually executing?
When a statement is wrapped in double quotes " " try referring variables in { }

```
   $logarchiveSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO log (logaction, logdivisionid, lognotes) VALUES ('Division Archived', %s, 'archived by {$_SESSION[MM_Username]} ')",
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['divisionid'], "int"));
```

Comment: Sorry, yes, the quey is executing, but the result i get does not include the username set by the session

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provided the error I checked the code and didnt find anything serious codingwise. However, some small suggestions as follows:

```
<?Php
if ((isset($_GET['divisionid'])) && ($_GET['divisionid'] != "")) {


    $logarchiveSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO log (logaction, logdivisionid, lognotes) VALUES ('Division Archived', %d, 'archived by %s')",
        GetSQLValueString($_GET['divisionid'], "int"), 
        $_SESSION['MM_Username']);

    mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
    $Result2 = mysql_query($logarchiveSQL, $connect) or die(mysql_error());


    $updateGoTo = "../divisions.php";
    if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
        $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
        $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    }
    header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
    exit;
}
?>
```

- You should use %d or %f for INT and FLOAT values respectively.
- Since you are using sprintf, why not use another %s to place the SESSION variable?
- You should place a EXIT after each header() call to ensure nothing
  more from this page executes after the program logic is transferred
  to another page.
- PHP is case sensitive and hence would recommend you to check the case
  of the SESSION variable with the one being used here.

Ultimately will appreciate the error you are facing!

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i'll apply them through out the rest of my system. The session username is still not posting in to the lognote value. The result im getting is "Division Archived  archived by  20th May 2012 - 13:10 pm"

Comment: if you check/search your code for `$_SESSION['MM_Username']=`, you will find an assignment action which updates that session variable with a date/time value which is being set here when you are accessing that value.

Comment: sorry, ignore the date - it's a timestamp value which updates when the query runs

Comment: Then your session variable is either not set or set to a blank value. You can check the assignment operations before your code executes to check for the same.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Thanks everyone for their help!

I didn't have the session_start declared, i'd forgotten that it's defined in my secure include file.

I also had to create a division recordset

```
    session_start();

$colname_division = "-1";
if ((isset($_GET['divisionid'])) && ($_GET['divisionid'] != "")) {
      $colname_division = $_GET['divisionid'];

mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
$query_division = sprintf("SELECT * FROM division WHERE divisionid = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_division, "int"));
$division = mysql_query($query_division, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
$row_division = mysql_fetch_assoc($division);
$totalRows_division = mysql_num_rows($division);


// ADD LOG DIVISION REINSTATED
    $logarchiveSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO log (logaction, logdivisionid, lognotes) VALUES ('Reinstated', %d, '" . $row_division['division'] . " reinstated by " . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . "')",
                    GetSQLValueString($_GET['divisionid'], "int")); 

    mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
    $Result1 = mysql_query($logarchiveSQL, $connect) or die(mysql_error());

// MESSAGE USERS DIVISION REINSTATED
    $messageinsertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES ('The division " . $row_division['division'] . " has been reinstated by " . $_SESSION['MM_Username'] . " you may now select this division')",
                    GetSQLValueString($_GET['divisionid'], "int")); 

    mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
    $Result4 = mysql_query($messageinsertSQL, $connect) or die(mysql_error());

// UPDATE DIVISION TO REINSTATED
    $divisionarchiveSQL = sprintf("UPDATE division SET divisionarchive=0 WHERE divisionid=%s",
                    GetSQLValueString($_GET['divisionid'], "int"));

    mysql_select_db($database_connect, $connect);
    $Result3 = mysql_query($divisionarchiveSQL, $connect) or die(mysql_error());

// REDIRECT
    $updateGoTo = "../divisions.php";
        if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
            $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
            $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
    header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));

    mysql_free_result($division);
    exit;
```